# Extension of scalar in tensor

Tags: modules, tensor-products

In the book ('introduction to commutative algebra' by Atiyah), from $A$-module $M$, we get an $A$-module $M_B=B\otimes_A M$ that has a $B$-module structure such that $b(b'\otimes x)=(bb'\otimes x)$ for any $b,b'\in B$ and all $x\in M$ provided that there is a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ (view $B$ as an $A$ module via $f$). How is this operation possible? $b$ is in $B$ not $A$. And also, once we get $M_B$, then is it both $A$-module and $B$-module? I'm a beginner in module theory so I want explanation in detail. any comment will be appreciated

Edit: $A,B$ are commutative rings with unity.

Comment: Which book is it and where? Is $A$ commutative with unit? If you want "an explanation in detail" you also have to explain in detail.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My bad. I just edit the post

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? You make the tensor product of two $A$-modules (over $A$) and it happens that one of them has a $B$-module structure, from which you can define a $B$-module structure on the tensor product. For instance you may have an integral domain $A$ and $B$ may be its field of fractions $K$. This way, from an $A$-module $M$, you deduce the $K$-vector space $K\otimes_AM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be both an $A$-module and a $B$-module.  The $A$-action on $M_B$ is defined using your $f$, namely if $a \in A$ then $a \cdot (b \otimes x) = (f(a) \cdot b) \otimes x$.  This makes sense since $f(a) \in B$ by definition of $f$.  This will be an action because $f$ is a homomorphism, so all the linearity conditions will be satisfied.

A lot of this left/right/bi-module stuff can be annoying and easy to forget; don't be frustrated, it was annoying for everyone who ever learned it, including Atiyah, Serre and Grothendieck I'm sure haha  It's good that you are trying to nail it down, because it can be useful to know for some slick categorical proofs later on in the theory.